# Loop within a loop indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a HTML table using JSON to populate it.

Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "grid": {
        "name": "JsonGrid",
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "ID",
                "width": "100px"
            },
            {
                "name": "Name",
                "width": "100%"
            },
            {
                "name": "Departments",
                "width": "250px"
            },
            {
                "name": "Locations",
                "width": "250px"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Company A",
            "departments": [
                "Software",
                "Recruitment",
                "Consulting"
            ],
            "locations": [
                "Sheffield",
                "Rotherham",
                "London",
                "New York"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Company B",
            "departments": "",
            "locations": [
                "Hillsborough",
                "City Centre",
                "Crystal Peaks"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Company C",
            "departments": [
                "Medical",
                "Family",
                "Criminal"
            ],
            "locations": [
                "Sheffield",
                "Rotherham"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the function that loops through the data object:

```
function addDataFromJson(json)
{
    var data = json.data;

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) // for each row
    {
        var columns = '';

        for(var b=0;b<Object.keys(data[i]).length;b++) // for each column
        {
            var content = data[i][b];

            console.log(content);

            columns += '<td>'+content+'</td>';
        }

        var row = columns;

        $( '<tr>' + row + '</tr>' ).appendTo('.uiGridContent tbody').hide().fadeIn();
    }
}
```

So I loop through to get the rows and look inside to find what columns I need, and then try and put the data into each column and then append the row. The columns and rows are perfect, but the data never gets pulled out!

It looks like I'm getting confused as I step into the second loop that pulls the actual data for each column. What should the content variable contain? Taking into consideration that sometimes the content may contain arrays instead of just strings.

Comment: What does google chrome debugger says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of `b`, it is just an index of the key not the actual property key so you need

```
var content = data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[b]];
```

like

```js
var json = {
  "grid": {
    "name": "JsonGrid",
    "columns": [{
      "name": "ID",
      "width": "100px"
    }, {
      "name": "Name",
      "width": "100%"
    }, {
      "name": "Departments",
      "width": "250px"
    }, {
      "name": "Locations",
      "width": "250px"
    }]
  },
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company A",
    "departments": [
      "Software",
      "Recruitment",
      "Consulting"
    ],
    "locations": [
      "Sheffield",
      "Rotherham",
      "London",
      "New York"
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Company B",
    "departments": "",
    "locations": [
      "Hillsborough",
      "City Centre",
      "Crystal Peaks"
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Company C",
    "departments": [
      "Medical",
      "Family",
      "Criminal"
    ],
    "locations": [
      "Sheffield",
      "Rotherham"
    ]
  }]
};

function addDataFromJson(json) {
  var data = json.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) // for each row
  {
    var columns = '',
      keys = Object.keys(data[i]);

    for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) // for each column
    {
      var content = data[i][keys[b]];

      console.log(content);

      columns += '<td>' + content + '</td>';
    }

    var row = columns;

    $('<tr>' + row + '</tr>').appendTo('.uiGridContent tbody').hide().fadeIn();
  }
}

addDataFromJson(json)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="uiGridContent">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

---

A more simpler way will be

```js
var json = {
  "grid": {
    "name": "JsonGrid",
    "columns": [{
      "name": "ID",
      "width": "100px"
    }, {
      "name": "Name",
      "width": "100%"
    }, {
      "name": "Departments",
      "width": "250px"
    }, {
      "name": "Locations",
      "width": "250px"
    }]
  },
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company A",
    "departments": [
      "Software",
      "Recruitment",
      "Consulting"
    ],
    "locations": [
      "Sheffield",
      "Rotherham",
      "London",
      "New York"
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Company B",
    "departments": "",
    "locations": [
      "Hillsborough",
      "City Centre",
      "Crystal Peaks"
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Company C",
    "departments": [
      "Medical",
      "Family",
      "Criminal"
    ],
    "locations": [
      "Sheffield",
      "Rotherham"
    ]
  }]
};

function addDataFromJson(json) {
  var data = json.data;

  var rows = $.map(data, function(record) {
    var cols = $.map(record, function(value, key) {
      return '<td>' + value + '</td>';
    })
    return '<tr>' + cols + '</tr>';
  })
  $(rows.join('')).hide().appendTo('.uiGridContent tbody').fadeIn();
}

addDataFromJson(json)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="uiGridContent">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use ECMAScript 5.1 helpers for better understanding what your code makes:

```
function addDataFromJSON(json) {
  //just check that data is array
  var data = json && Array.isArray(json.data) ? json.data : [];

  data.forEach(function(rowObject) {
    //every loop will create a row
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    Object.keys(rowObject).forEach(function(cellKey) {
      //every loop will create a cell
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = rowObject[cellKey];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });

    table.appendChild(tr);

  });

}
```

```js
var table = document.querySelector('#table');
var jsonData = {
  "data": [{ //this is row
    "id": 1, // this is a cell value
    "name": "Company A",
    "departments": [
      "Software",
      "Recruitment",
      "Consulting"
    ],
    "locations": [
      "Sheffield",
      "Rotherham",
      "London",
      "New York"
    ]
  }, { //this is one more row
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Company B",
    "departments": "",
    "locations": [
      "Hillsborough",
      "City Centre",
      "Crystal Peaks"
    ]
  }]
};

function addDataFromJSON(json) {
  //just check that data is array
  var data = json && Array.isArray(json.data) ? json.data : [];

  data.forEach(function(rowObject) {
    //every loop will create a row
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    Object.keys(rowObject).forEach(function(cellKey) {
      //every loop will create a cell
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = rowObject[cellKey];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });

    table.appendChild(tr);

  });

}

addDataFromJSON(jsonData);
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id=table></table>
</body>

</html>
```